# Play! Framework 2.0.3, i18n error, `=' expected but `-' found

Tags: java, scala, internationalization, playframework

I'm new in "Play! Framework" and I'm trying to do a i18n for pt-BR.

My message file is called 'Message.pt-BR' and i put the pt-BR lang in application.conf.

In Java I'm using something like this:

```
flash("success", Messages.get("logout.success"));
```

And in scala.html files I'm using this:

```
@Messages("logout")
```

In my Message.pt-BR file I've this:

```
logout=Sair
logout.success=Logout realizado com sucesso. Volte sempre!
```

When I compile the project I have no errors, but when I request some page a have this error:

```
`=' expected but `-' found
Messages.pt-BR
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any `-` in `Message.pt-BR` file?

Comment: Yes, the Message.pt-BR content is just what I say in post. The erro points to '-' in the 'pt-BR'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to rename your message file from `Messages.pt-BR` to `Messages.pt_BR` (with a lower '_').